# Scikit SVR Predicting Polynomial using X's with multiple y's

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So as the question states I am looking to make a prediction given a range of 12 X points all of these X points have 9 y points. So the prediction is based on only 1 attribute.

Using nested lists (i.e. [[1,2,...],...]) doesn't seem to work. I think I am generally looking at the wrong thing to use. I am using SVR with kernel on poly, this works on data which has distinct X and y.

Following is what my data looks like, I did find another thread with the reverse issue but that didn't help me out. If I need to add more info let me know so I can edit the question!

[Figure showing Data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcAam.png) The redline is hardcoded and meant to illustrate what I want of course in a polynomial form fitting the data points minimising the error to each point. (Which is what the SVR should be doing but the problem lies in format of the to be fitted data)

Comment: Not clear. So you want to predict a set of 9 values from a single value?

Comment: EDIT: I have edited the question. If you look at the picture provided, I want to get the polynomial through the data set that minimises the error to each point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is reasonably simple. Taking the average of the datapoints and using those instead will yield you the same results. Deduced from the following sources: [One](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/69016-curve-fitting-with-multiple-y-data-point-for-each-x), [Two](https://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/Math-AveCurve). So in my case I will average the y values for each X giving me 12 X values and 12 y values. Without knowing this exactly I am assuming it has to do with the sum of errors being equal to the error of the sum.